# how to get specific folder with the help of environment.getexternalstoragedirectory()

Tags: android, directory

I have created an ArrayList to scan .mp3 files from external storage:

```
final ArrayList<File> myplaylist0 = findSongs0(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

Function findsongs0 is shown below:

```
public ArrayList<File> findSongs0(File root){
    ArrayList<File> al=new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    for(File singleFile : files){
        if(singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()){
            al.addAll(findSongs(singleFile));
        }
        else
        {
            if(singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav")){
                al.add(singleFile);

            }
        }
    }
    return al;
}
```

The above codes give me list of all .mp3 files from my phone storage.

Now, my question is, how to scan mp3 files from the particular folder instead of whole storage. What should I modify in the above code??

Comment: pass as argument `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"<your_mp3_folder>" `

Comment: @Radix it's not working....gives an error: findsongs0(java.io.File) cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Comment: Because effectively that line returns a path. Since your argument takes in a File , you should be passing `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"<your_mp3_folder>")`

Comment: @Radix  Thank you.. it worked

Comment: Thank you. I have added it as an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument should be like

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"<your_mp3_folder>")
```

i.e

```
File myfile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"<your_mp3_folder>")
final ArrayList<File> myplaylist0 = findSongs0(myfile);
```